# Java add var to Object on initialization

Tags: java, object

I want to add a new Object to my Object "yamlFile" at initialization.

```
public yamlFile config = new yamlFile() {

    protected ServerGroup GROUP_BELOW_16, GROUP_16, GROUP_17, GROUP_18, GROUP_ABOVE_18;

    @Override
    public void load() {
        super.load();
        try {
            GROUP_BELOW_16 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.-16"));
            GROUP_16 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.16"));
            GROUP_17 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.17"));
            GROUP_18 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.18"));
            GROUP_ABOVE_18 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.+18"));
        } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
            Bot.getLogger().warning("Path existiert nicht");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}.setFolder("data").setFilename("config.yml").build();
```

So in the Object yamlFile there are no "ServerGroup" objects. So i want to add some. So i added them on initialization but they arent accessable from anywhere else. So i can´t use them in an other method like:

```
public void method(){
    config.GROUP_16 = null;
}
```

My Question: What must i do to make the ServerGroup objects accessable without implementing them in the "original" yamlFile class?

Original yamlFile class:

```
public class yamlFile {

    /**
     * 
     * var methods
     * 
     **/
    private String folder;
    private String filename;

    public String getFolder() {
        return folder;
    }

    public yamlFile setFolder(String folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
        return this;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public yamlFile setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * file methods
     * 
     **/
    private File file;

    public yamlFile set() {
        file = new File(getFolder(), getFilename());
        return this;
    }

    final private YamlConfiguration yamlConfiguration = new YamlConfiguration();

    /**
     * Checks for the specific file if it exists.
     */
    public void fileExists() throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {

            if (!file.exists()) {
                yamlConfiguration.options().copyDefaults(true);
                file = new File(getFolder(), getFilename());
                yamlConfiguration.save(file);
            }
        } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void load() {
        try {
            fileExists();
        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            Bot.getLogger().info("Creating file: " + getFolder() + "/" + getFilename());
        }
        try {

            yamlConfiguration.load(file);

        } catch (final FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final InvalidConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void save() {
        try {
            yamlConfiguration.save(file);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public YamlConfiguration getFile() {
        return yamlConfiguration;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is a reason to make your extension anonymous? Why can you modify the original YAML File class?

Comment: I added the yamlFile class to the post. I use this class for every file, to make multiple files more faster, and i dont load the same vars from every file. So i want to make the vars, loaded from the file, accessable only from the Object itsel. So: i dont need an config.yml var in a object called data, where some other data is saved.

Comment: Why not just extend it and add your properties?  You can't usefully add public methods with an anonymous class like this.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that your YamlFile contains the commons properties of different configuration files... however, there is a particular configuration (the ServerGroup One), that you want to read/store in the configuration, but you don't want to expose as a common configuration property, right?

Comment: @CarlitosWay Yes, that is that what i want to do

Comment: Right now, how the clients of the YamlFile API consume configurations that are not commons?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an interface (eg. ServerGroupYamlFile) that extends yamlFile. This interface would include your methods.

```
public ServerGroup getGroup16(){
   return config.GROUP_16;
}
```

Then, you implement your interface:

```
public yamlFile config = new ServerGroupYamlFile() { ....
```

Then you have the flexibility to add any method your yaml class.

If the list of groups is dynamic, then just provide a method on the interface that returns a list of groups.

```
public List<ServerGroup> getGroups(){
   return yourGroups;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for the answers!** I just found the solution because of lan McLaird comment!
I just make an new inner-class which extends yamlFile and then add my properties there.

If someone could need this code i post it here:

```
public class FileManager {

    public class config extends yamlFile {
        public ServerGroup GROUP_BELOW_16, GROUP_16, GROUP_17, GROUP_18, GROUP_ABOVE_18;

        @Override
        public void load() {
            super.load();
            try {
                GROUP_BELOW_16 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.-16"));
                GROUP_16 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.16"));
                GROUP_17 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.17"));
                GROUP_18 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.18"));
                GROUP_ABOVE_18 = Bot.getServergroupById(Bot.getFileManager().getConfigConfiguration().getInt("age.+18"));
            } catch (final NullPointerException e) {
                Bot.getLogger().warning("Path existiert nicht");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public config config = (api.filemanager.FileManager.config) new config().setFolder("data").setFilename("config.yml").set();

    public YamlConfiguration getConfigConfiguration() {
        return config.getFile();
    }

    public config getConfig() {
        return config;
    }
}
```